# Liquibase arquivo .sql não encontrado

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Quando executo o liquibase ele não encontra arquivos .slq configurados pela tag. SQLFile. como se resolve isso?

Dados do problema:

- Uso no projeto o liquibase 3.4.2.
- Configurado o plugin do maven
- Executo script no Maven **Ok funciona tudo** (Windows + Eclipse + plugin)
- Executo plugin maven, No Eclise
- **No ambiente de produção tenho o .war, e não tenho o maven.**
- Colocando em produção

Como não tenho mais o maven, executo o comando pelo jar do liquibase
chamado **liquibase-core-3.4.2**.
Executa até o changeSet onde tem arquivos SQLFile configrado como se vê abaixo

```
<changeSet author="aut-01" id="municipios-1"  runInTransaction="true" context="local, test, homolog, production" runOnChange="false">
    <comment> first 3 municipios </comment>
    <sqlFile path="sql/municipios-0-78.sql" endDelimiter=";" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <rollback />
</changeSet>
```

Erro gerado

```
SEVERE  PM: liquibase: WEB-INF/classes/changelogs/versions/1.0.0.0/db.changelog-municipios-br-1.0.0.0.xml::municipios-1::aut-01: 
    File does not exist: 'sql/municipios-0-78.sql'
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.io.IOException: File does not exist: 'sql/municipios-0-78.sql'
    at liquibase.change.AbstractSQLChange.generateCheckSum(AbstractSQLChange.java:179)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.generateCheckSum(ChangeSet.java:251)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.toString(ChangeSet.java:770)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.createKey(ChangeLogIterator.java:107)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.alreadySaw(ChangeLogIterator.java:115)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:78)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:259)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1130)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File does not exist: 'sql/municipios-0-78.sql'
    at liquibase.change.core.SQLFileChange.openSqlStream(SQLFileChange.java:112)
    at liquibase.change.AbstractSQLChange.generateCheckSum(AbstractSQLChange.java:166)
... 11 more
```

Estrutura dos arquivos (Executando em Linux Ubuntu)

```
...
    - changelogs
        db.changelog-master.xml
        - versions
            - 1.0.0.0
                .
                .
                .
                db.changelog-municipios-br-1.0.0.0.xml
                - sql
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    municipios-0-78.sql
```

Isso é bug, achei uma issue no projeto [Liquibase Jira](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1081)

Comment: Vejo que você usou `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`. Tem certeza que o arquivo 'sql/municipios-0-78.sql' existe em relação ao arquivo de ChangeLog?

Comment: Sim existe, em ambiente de desenvolvimento funciona, pelo plugin do maven, em produção não. mas em produção uso o arquivo .jar passando seus devidos parametros

Comment: Bem a mensagem indica que ele não encontra o arquivo. Poste a estrutura do seu projeto, no ambiente onde ocorre o erro. Se realmente existir pode ser um problema com as permissões do arquivo.

Comment: Sim, não achar o arquivo, porque acho que não esta montando a path corretamente, pois ele esta lá, atualizei coloquei os diretórios como estão. executo como root então não é problema de permissão